# How to create transparent start orb image using illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I designed a start orb bitmap with illustrator in specified dimensions(66x198px)..
When i saved and set it as my start button.. Though its transparent, some Faded white background is applied to the start button.. How to create transparent start orb image using illustrator.. ?
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

1) Apply an appropriate effect (I Like Distort | Diffuse Glow)

2) Export as PNG and ensure the background color on the PNG options dialog is Transparent.

3) Open PNG in Photoshop and delete "almost white" colors.

4) Enjoy

[image]